# Just what is <<pseudo:before>></<pseudo:before>> and is it useful to me?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

Playing around in Chrome, I noticed that if you copy a pseudo element (e.g. `::before`) from the element inspector, and paste the results, you'll get the following:

```
<<pseudo:before>></<pseudo:before>>
```

I can't find any reference to this syntax, and it got me wondering:

1. Is this merely Chrome/webkit's way of allowing the inspection of pseudo elements in dev tools, or is this part of a wider spec?
2. Are there any cases/reasons that this may be of use to a developer, such as (probably unlikely) outputting this syntax directly to emulate CSS pseudo selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***info:*** That's the [`The outerHTML attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) of the *`::before pseudo-element`* in DOM.

As that *`element`* does not have any *"real"* content in it <sup>*(<s>it has</s> could have a **CSS `content:''`** property)*</sup>...
...you only get the `outerHTML` when you copy <sup>*(& paste)*</sup>

I don't think and AFAIK, ***can't be emulate/simulate*** this `pseudo-element` directly in DOM.

---

Now.. `outerHTML` is supported in all mayor browser at these days... and with `Javascript` you can can have an approach ***emu/simulating***, but I don't know if that's really your question.

---

***Edit:*** Screenshot added so you can find the reference of `outerHTML` directly in Chrome DevTools.

```
#question-header h1:before {
    content: 'Hi there! ';
    color: red;
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P5i1w6Q.png]

Comment: I understand what you mean by the element not having any "real" content, but I can't see anything in your citation that corroborates it's the outerHTML attribute... can you provide anything that explains/supports this?

Comment: I will upload a screenshot in a minute... (edit: and a few minutes later... done!)

Comment: Aha... interesting, thanks. As firebug's element inspector doesn't offer anything similar, I assume this must be webkit-specific. I'm still left thinking that this must have an unintended use-case though.